# removing columns from a large list if the dataframe has that column

Tags: r, list

I used extract_tables from the package tabulizer to extract a 165 page table. each page was formatted into it's own data frame in a large list. The table in the PDF has 5 columns. Some of the pages were incorrectly formatted to only have 4 columns.

I want to combine all of the dataframes into a single dataframe but I cannot because the column numbers are different.

The fifth column is a little unncessary so I was tring the map_if function

```
map_if(df, ~.[,5], ~ select(-c(,5)))
```

However that is not working.

EDIT:
To simplify the problem I am copying and pasting output a shortened version of my data.

Using `typeof()`, my data is a list, using `length()` length of this shortened dataset is 7. `str()` returns the following values:

```
List of 7

 $ : chr [1:34, 1:4] "Species" "Abelmoschus\t\r  esculentus(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Moench" "Abelmoschus\t\r  esculentus(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Moench" "Abelmoschus\t\r  ficulneus(\t\r  \t\r  L.)\t\r  Wight\t\r  &\t\r  Arn." ...

$ : chr [1:34, 1:4] "Species" "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L." "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L." "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L." ...

$ : chr [1:34, 1:4] "Species" "Acanthocalyx\t\r  alba(\t\r  Hand.-Â­â\200\220Mazz.)\t\r  M.J.Cannon" "Acanthus\t\r  ilicifolius\t\r  L." "Achillea\t\r  millefolium\t\r  L." ...

$ : chr [1:34, 1:4] "Species" "Achyranthes\t\r  bidentata\t\r  Blume" "Achyranthes\t\r  bidentata\t\r  Blume" "Achyranthes\t\r  bidentata\t\r  Blume" ...

$ : chr [1:34, 1:4] "Species" "Adhatoda\t\r  vasica\t\r  Nees" "Adhatoda\t\r  vasica\t\r  Nees" "Adhatoda\t\r  vasica\t\r  Nees" ...

$ : chr [1:34, 1:4] "Species" "Aganosma\t\r  marginata(\t\r  Roxb.)\t\r  G.Don" "Aganosma\t\r  marginata(\t\r  Roxb.)\t\r  G.Don" "Aganosma\t\r  sp." ...

$ : chr [1:34, 1:5] "Species" "Ailanthus\t\r  triphysa(\t\r  Dennst.)\t\r  Alston" "Ainsliaea\t\r  \t\r  spicata\t\r  Vaniot" "Akebia\t\r  quinata(\t\r  Houtt.)\t\r  Decne." ...
```

The output for dput(pdf.dat[1:2])

```
list(structure(c("Species", "Abelmoschus\t\r  esculentus(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Moench", 
"Abelmoschus\t\r  esculentus(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Moench", "Abelmoschus\t\r  ficulneus(\t\r  \t\r  L.)\t\r  Wight\t\r  &\t\r  Arn.", 
"Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", "Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", 
"Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", "Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", 
"Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", "Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", 
"Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", "Abelmoschus\t\r  manihot(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Medik.", 
"Abelmoschus\t\r  moschatus\t\r  Medik.", "Abelmoschus\t\r  moschatus\t\r  Medik.", 
"Abelmoschus\t\r  sagittifolius(\t\r  Kurz)\t\r  Merr.", "Abelmoschus\t\r  sagittifolius(\t\r  Kurz)\t\r  Merr.", 
"Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", "Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", 
"Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", "Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", 
"Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", "Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", 
"Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", "Abroma\t\r  augusta(\t\r  L.)\t\r  L.\t\r  f.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Family", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", 
"Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", 
"Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", 
"Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", 
"Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Fabaceae", 
"Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", 
"Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Use", "Hysteritis", "Blenorrhagia", 
"Contraceptive", "Parturition", "Menorrhagia", "Parturition(\t\r  difficult)", 
"Female\t\r  fertility", "Parturition(\t\r  induces\t\r  labour)", 
"Lactagogue", "Blenorrhagia", "Postpartum\t\r  recovery", "Gynaecological\t\r  diseases", 
"Lactagogue", "Blenorrhagia", "Leucorrhea", "Dysmenorrhea", "uterine\t\r  diseases", 
"Leucorrhea", "Menstrual\t\r  disorders", "Amenorrhea", "Dysmenorrhea", 
"Emmenagogue", "Dysmenorrhea", "Antifertility/prevent\t\r  conception", 
"Abortifacient", "Contraception", "Amenorrhegia", "Neonatal\t\r  bath", 
"Contraceptive", "Abortifacient", "Abortifacient", "Abortifacient", 
"Abortifacient", "Use(\t\r  standardized)\t\r   Study", "Inflammation Kishore\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  1989)", 
"Leucorrhea PÃ©telot(\t\r  1952)", "Contraceptive Bhogaonkar\t\r  and\t\r  Kadam(\t\r  2011)", 
"Other/NOS Bourdy\t\r  and\t\r  Walter(\t\r  1992)", "Uterine\t\r  hemorrhage Bourdy\t\r  and\t\r  Walter(\t\r  1992)", 
"Parturition\t\r   Girard\t\r  and\t\r  Barrau(\t\r  1957)", 
"Fertility Holdsworth(\t\r  1975)", "Uterine\t\r  contractions(\t\r  induce) Holdsworth(\t\r  1980)", 
"Lactation(\t\r  stimulate) Ishidoya(\t\r  1933-Â­â\200\2201937)", 
"Leucorrhea Roi(\t\r  1955)", "Postpartum\t\r  recovery Roosita\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2008)", 
"Gynecological\t\r  disorders\t\r  NOS Van\t\r  Duong(\t\r  1993)", 
"Lactation(\t\r  stimulate) Zhang\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2009)", 
"Leucorrhea PÃ©telot(\t\r  1952)", "Leucorrhea PÃ©telot(\t\r  1952)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  pain Guerrero(\t\r  1922)", "Gynecological\t\r  disorders\t\r  NOS Hossan\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2010)", 
"Leucorrhea Hossan\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2010)", "Menstrual\t\r  disorders\t\r  NOS Hossan\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2010)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  flow(\t\r  absent) Pardo\t\r  de\t\r  Tavera\t\r  and\t\r  Thomas(\t\r  1901)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  pain Pardo\t\r  de\t\r  Tavera\t\r  and\t\r  Thomas(\t\r  1901)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  flow(\t\r  stimulate) PÃ©telot(\t\r  1952)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  pain Quisumbing(\t\r  1951)", "Contraceptive Behera(\t\r  2006)", 
"Abortion(\t\r  induce) Bhattarai(\t\r  1994)", "Contraceptive Bhattarai(\t\r  1994)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  flow(\t\r  absent) Bhogaonkar\t\r  and\t\r  Kadam(\t\r  2011)", 
"Other/NOS Fox(\t\r  1953)", "Contraceptive Goswami\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2011)", 
"Abortion(\t\r  induce) Guha\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2003)", "Abortion(\t\r  induce) Jain\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2004)", 
"Abortion(\t\r  induce) Kalita\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2011)", 
"Abortion(\t\r  induce) Kishore\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  1989)"
), .Dim = c(34L, 4L)), structure(c("Species", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", 
"Abrus\t\r  precatorius\t\r  L.", "Abutilon\t\r  indicum(\t\r  \t\r  L.)\t\r  Sweet", 
"Abutilon\t\r  indicum(\t\r  \t\r  L.)\t\r  Sweet", "Abutilon\t\r  indicum(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Sweet", 
"Abutilon\t\r  indicum(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Sweet", "Acacia\t\r  catechu(\t\r  L.\t\r  f.)\t\r  Willd.", 
"Acacia\t\r  catechu(\t\r  L.f.)\t\r  Willd.", "Acacia\t\r  concinna(\t\r  Willd.)\t\r  DC.", 
"Acacia\t\r  concinna(\t\r  Willd.)\t\r  DC.", "Acacia\t\r  farnesiana(\t\r  \t\r  L.)\t\r  Willd.", 
"Acacia\t\r  farnesiana(\t\r  \t\r  L.)\t\r  Willd.", "Acacia\t\r  farnesiana(\t\r  \t\r  L.)\t\r  Willd.", 
"Acacia\t\r  farnesiana(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Willd.", "Acacia\t\r  farnesiana(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Willd.", 
"Acacia\t\r  farnesiana(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Willd.", "Acacia\t\r  leucophloeia(\t\r  Roxb.)\t\r  Willd.", 
"Acacia\t\r  leucophloeia(\t\r  Roxb.)\t\r  Willd.", "Acacia\t\r  nilotica(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Delile", 
"Acacia\t\r  nilotica(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Delile", "Acacia\t\r  nilotica(\t\r  L.)\t\r  Delile", 
"Acalypha\t\r  grandis\t\r  Benth.", "Acalypha\t\r  spiciflora\t\r  Burm.f.", 
"Acalypha\t\r  spiciflora\t\r  Burm.f.", "Acanthocalyx\t\r  alba(\t\r  Hand.-Â­â\200\220Mazz.)\t\r  M.J.Cannon", 
"Family", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", 
"Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Malvaceae", 
"Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Malvaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", 
"Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", 
"Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", "Fabaceae", 
"Fabaceae", "Euphorbiaceae", "Euphorbiaceae", "Euphorbiaceae", 
"Caprifoliaceae", "Use", "Contraceptive", "Female\t\r  fertility", 
"Leucorrhea", "Abortifacient", "Contraceptive", "Antifertility", 
"Postpartum\t\r  recovery", "Contraceptive", "Abortifacient", 
"menstrual\t\r  disorders", "menstrual\t\r  disorders", "Leucorrhea", 
"Urinary\t\r  tract\t\r  infections", "Uterus\t\r  displacement", 
"Abortifacient", "Abortifacient", "Postpartum", "Postpartum", 
"Leucorrhea", "Leucorrhea", "Menorrhagia", "Postpartum\t\r  protective", 
"Leucorrhea", "Gynaecological\t\r  diseases", "Contraceptive", 
"Amenorrhea", "Contraction\t\r  of\t\r  uterus\t\r  in\t\r  post-Â­â\200\220natal\t\r  days", 
"Menstrual\t\r  pain\t\r  relief", "Leucorrhea", "Contraceptive", 
"postpartum\t\r  anemia", "expel\t\r  lochia", "Gynaecological\t\r  diseases", 
"Use(\t\r  standardized)\t\r   Study", "Contraceptive Pal\t\r  and\t\r  Jain(\t\r  1998),\t\r  Lodha", 
"Fertility Pal\t\r  and\t\r  Jain(\t\r  1998),\t\r  Lodha", "Leucorrhea Pal\t\r  and\t\r  Jain(\t\r  1998),\t\r  Lodha", 
"Abortion(\t\r  induce) Panduranga\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2011)", 
"Contraceptive Panduranga\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2011)", "Contraceptive Priya\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2002)", 
"Postpartum\t\r  recovery Roosita\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2008)", 
"Contraceptive Tripathi\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2010)", "Abortion(\t\r  induce) Van\t\r  Duong(\t\r  1993)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  disorders\t\r  NOS Vidyasagar\t\r  and\t\r  Prashantkumar(\t\r  2007)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  disorders\t\r  NOS Panduranga\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2011)", 
"Leucorrhea Yadav\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2006)", "Urinary\t\r  tract\t\r  infections Lecomte\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  1907)", 
"Uterine\t\r  prolapse Mohapatra\t\r  and\t\r  Sahoo(\t\r  2008)", 
"Abortion(\t\r  induce) Jain\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2004)", "Abortion(\t\r  induce) Bhattarai(\t\r  1994)", 
"Other/NOS Anderson(\t\r  1993),\t\r  Hmong", "Other/NOS Anderson(\t\r  1993),\t\r  Karen", 
"Leucorrhea PÃ©telot(\t\r  1952)", "Leucorrhea Tripathi\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2010)", 
"Uterine\t\r  hemorrhage Tripathi\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2010)", 
"Other/NOS Gimlette(\t\r  1930)", "Leucorrhea Pardo\t\r  de\t\r  Tavera\t\r  and\t\r  Thomas(\t\r  1901)", 
"Gynecological\t\r  disorders\t\r  NOS Van\t\r  Duong(\t\r  1993)", 
"Contraceptive Jain\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2004)", "Menstrual\t\r  flow(\t\r  absent) Jain\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2004)", 
"Postpartum\t\r  uterus\t\r  reduction Bhattarai(\t\r  1994)", 
"Menstrual\t\r  pain Pal\t\r  and\t\r  Jain(\t\r  1998),\t\r  Lodha", 
"Leucorrhea Yadav\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2006)", "Contraceptive Bourdy\t\r  and\t\r  Walter(\t\r  1992)", 
"Anemia Panyaphu\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2011)", "Uterine\t\r  contractions(\t\r  induce) Panyaphu\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2011)", 
"Gynecological\t\r  disorders\t\r  NOS Liu\t\r  et\t\r  al.(\t\r  2009)"
), .Dim = c(34L, 4L)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is called `list_df`, you can `select` first 4 columns :

```
library(dplyr)
all_data <- purrr::map_df(pdf.dat,~as.data.frame(.x) %>% select(1:4))
```

Or in base R :

```
all_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(pdf.dat, function(x) data.frame(x)[1:4]))
```